# Case when statement, syntax error

Tags: sql-update, case, ssms, case-when

Below are the code that I am trying to us and the error that I am receiving. The task seems rather simple but not sure how to proceed. When the area value is 000995, 000996, 000998, or 000999 I need the areatype to change to 07. If it is not one of those 4 then change it to 04. The table being updated has 22 fields. Areatype and area are char (2) and char (6) respectively. I have tinkered with it and always back to square one.

```
 update [dbo.industry] set areatype = (case when (area 
 in('000995','000996','000998','000999’)) then '07' else '04' End);

 Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 229
 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.
 Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 229
 Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ' End);
 '.
```

Answer (score 0):

I knew that it would be a simple item but it is the strange curly que quote on the end of 000999